# Validate TextBox Based on radio button selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have these two radio buttons for the subscription. If the customer select yes radio button then I am showing enter email address textbox. If the customer selects yes then the email address textbox is mandatory. How do add conditional validation inside model?

Model :

```
public class CustomerModel  
{
  [Required]
  public bool Subscribe {get; set;}

  [RequiredIfYes]
  public string Email {ger; set;}
}
```

Custom validation class :

```
    public class RequiredIfYesAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == "Yes")
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Email is Required.");
        }
    }
}
```

View :

```html
 <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
                    <label class="required" for="subscribe">Email Subsciption</label>
                    <span >Yes : <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="Subscribe" id="chkYes" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" /></span>
                    <span >No : <input type="radio" value="No" name="Subscribe" id="chkNo" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" /></span>
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subscribe)
                </div>
                <div id="dvtext" style="display: none">
                    <label for="email" class="required">Enter Email</label>
                    <div style="width:300px;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You can look into [Foolproof Validation](https://www.leniel.net/2012/06/jquery-date-validation-foolproof-aspnet.html), this is the [GitHub project](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the custom validation:

```
 public class RequiredIfYesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var radioName = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Subscribe");
        string radioValue = radioName.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null)?.ToString();

        var emailName = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Email");
        string emailValue = emailName.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null)?.ToString();

        if (radioValue == "Yes" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailValue))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Email is Required.");
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I select No radio button, email text will be null. But it gives me an error at emailValue  "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Answer was updated. ***Null Conditional Operator*** `?` was added before the two `ToString()`s.